# My Httpd.conf file is blank

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to setup mono and apache, its setup and working, but now I want to add the mono control panel and also a host to the web site,

I've just opened httpd.conf, and the file is completely empty. Is there a way to generate a proper template for this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention which major version of Apache you're on. I believe different versions have slightly different option sets

However, a quick [favourite search engine] search for something along the lines of 'apache *version* httpd.conf example' should yield results for you

But, probably the bigger question you need to answer is why is the httpd.conf blank. That's worth looking in to

Comment: Apache 2.2.9 - And httpd.conf is obsolete

Comment: I've just checked an Apache 2 installation, httpd.conf exists. Admittedly, it only contains include statements for other .conf files, but it still exists

This is an old install though, so I don't know how much has changed since then

Answer (score 3):

Debian-based distributions leave a blank `httpd.conf` in `/etc/apache2`.  All of the actual configuration is in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.  Is that, perhaps, what you're seeing?

In either case, many distributions keep example config files in `/usr/share/doc/$pkgname`.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Search the file system for httpd.default.conf
2. Download the Apache source, and extract httpd.conf
3. Build your own: [Apache 2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/configuring.html), [Apache 1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/configuring.html)